# Is it clean to create an instance of a class inside a static method of that class?

Tags: c#, class, oop, static-methods, instantiation

I have a non-static class and a static method inside it. No doubts so far. but I create an instance of the same class in the static method. I am not sure, whether it will create a circular reference. I ran it in debug mode to see any unexpected behavior, but couldn't. However, I want to confirm this. Is it ok to create an instance of a class inside a static method in the same class? Is it a bad habit?

```
public class DownloadHelper
{
    //fields, properties

    public DownloadHelper()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public async Task<bool> HttpCalls()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return true;
    }

    public static async void GetPreparedInAdvance()
    {
        var helper = new DownloadHelper();
        var success = await helper.HttpCalls();
        // some more codes
    }
}

// Is it ok to call like this?
DownloadHelper.GetPreparedInAdvance();

// little later,
DownloadHelper.GetPreparedInAdvance();
```

Comment: It is fine to do this, but the only thing to keep in mind is that static member and methods make unit testing hard. There's a trade-off. Sometimes it's better to have a class `IDownloadHelperFactory factory = new DownloadHelperFactory()` that creates instance of `IDownloadHelper helper = factory.Create();`. This abstraction allow for easier unit testing. It depends on your circumstances what is best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem and what this code does is conventional.

Using static methods to create an object instance:

- May or may not be a [singleton pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) (you can ask yourself the question here):

  [Singleton Design Pattern In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/)
- Can also be a [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), but not here:

  [Factory Method Design Pattern In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/)

Here it is a variation of what I call a *static run method pattern**:

- It creates an object instance of the class on each call, or can be unique if singleton,
- It executes this instance : display a form, or download a file from the web, and so on,
- And it returns a result, or not : of the dialog box or of the file, and so on.

With such a pattern, constructors are generally private to ensure consistency.

---

**I have not yet studied the standard [design patterns](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns)*